# readonly in gvim windows

Tags: gvim

I don't know what causes it, but in Windows i use GVim (portable GVim), and need to open some file (that already exist, Vim didn't created it), but it opens it in readonly mode.
i need to use w! to write it. I have proper permissions on windows directory, but, this seems like some flag in Vim as it says:

```
E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)
```

i don't want to type w! to save, because Vim is supposed to be portable (run from USB in windows), so it needs to work with foreign files it didn't created. When i create file in Vim, it doesn't complain.

How this work under Windows?

And i already have these flags, but not working:

```
set noro
set noreadonly
set write
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set readonly` is set automatically if the target file has READONLY flag set in file system. Make sure you don't accidentally create files with READONLY flag set.

Comment: i'm not sure how that goes in windows. i can open in all other editors, and edit it and save it fine. so it means i have permission to write, right?

Comment: @IgorLerinc You can check all flags and permissions in file properties page by Windows explorer.